# Model not saving to MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, readline

I am trying to register a user and save the user to MongoDB. I am creating the user using nodejs `readline` module. But when I am trying to save it to the mongodb it is not working. Nor does it is returning any `error`.

**Here's the code**

```js
const { Admin, validate } = require('../models/admin');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const print_error = '\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m'; 
const print_success = '\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m'; 

function createUser() {
    rl.question('Please Enter Username : ', (username) => {
        rl.question('Please Enter a Password : ', async(password) => {
            const adminObject = {
                username,
                password
            };
            const { error } = validate(adminObject);
            if (error) {
                rl.close()
                rl.removeAllListeners()
                return console.log(print_error, error.details[0].message);
            }

            let admin = await new Admin({
                username: username,
                password: password
            });
            console.log(admin);
            const result = await admin.save(function(err,res){
                if(err){
                    console.log('err',err);
                    return console.log('err',err);
                }
                else return console.log('res', res);
            }); // save is not working
            console.log(print_success, result);
            rl.close(process.exit(1)); // close the process after done saving
        });
    });
}
createUser();
```

**Admin Model**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Joi = require('joi');

const Admin = new mongoose.model('Admin', new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 10,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength:3,
        maxlength: 1024
    }
}));

function validateAdmin(admin){
    const schema = {
        username: Joi.string().min(1).required(),
        password: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    };
    return Joi.validate(admin, schema);
}

exports.Admin = Admin;
exports.validate = validateAdmin;
```

**P.S** - I've connected to the mongodb, the connection is successful.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(print_success, result);`?

Comment: @TamasSzoke `undefined`

Comment: I've been update my answer and you can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know why you're use `async/await` and then you use `function` in your `save`.

You can change your `createUser` function with this code below:

```js
function createUser() {
    rl.question('Please Enter Username : ', (username) => {
        rl.question('Please Enter a Password : ', async(password) => {

            const { error } = validate({ username, password });

            if (error) {
                rl.close()
                rl.removeAllListeners()
                return console.log(print_error, error.details[0].message);
            }

            let admin = new Admin({username, password });

            try {
              const result = await admin.save(); 
              console.log(print_success, result);
              rl.close(process.exit(1)); 
            } catch(ex) {
              console.log(ex.message);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

> If you've any problem, then let me know in the comment below.

**Updated:** After test your code, you have no connection in your `createUser.js`.

I've been add this connection below in above of your `createUser()` and it's working:

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/url-shortener');
```

> Please, make sure you've add a connection to your `mongodb`.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Oh , I should either use `async/await` or `callback`. Sorry there. However, this isn't working :( If you want to have a look at my project here is it. [link](https://github.com/raghav4/shortlink), [file](https://github.com/raghav4/shortlink/blob/master/startup/createUser.js)

Comment: How to run your `createUser` function

Comment: Yes, it's working now! But can you please tell me why do we need to create MongoDB connection again if we have already done it once for the entire application?

Comment: When I see your `createUser()`, it is not related to the `index.js` that you have. If you only want to use your existing `mongodb` connection, then make sure you import` createUser() `into your` index.js` or at least if you use your existing routes, you can call `createUser()` from there and you don't have to make a new connection and it still works. But if you only call your `createUser` function from your `createUser.js` without import, so, you've to create a new connection, if not, it's will not working.